# Redshift - Adding timezone offset (Varchar) to timestamp column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, timezone-offset

as part of ETL to Redshift, in one of the source tables, there are 2 columns:
`original_timestamp - TIMESTAMP`: which is the local time when the record was inserted in whichever region
`original_timezone_offset - Varchar`: which is the offset to UTC

The data looks something like this:

```
original_timestamp      original_timezone_offset
2011-06-22 11:00:00.000000    -0700
2014-11-29 17:00:00.000000    -0800
2014-12-02 22:00:00.000000    +0900
2011-06-03 09:23:00.000000    -0700
2011-07-28 03:00:00.000000    -0700
2011-05-01 01:30:00.000000    -0700
```

In my target table, I need to convert this to UTC (using the offset). How do I do it?
So far I have tried multiple things but `dateadd()` seems to be the closest solution. But the problem with `dateadd()` is, when I say:

```
SELECT original_timestamp, original_timezone_offset
 ,dateadd(H, original_timezone_offset, original_timestamp) as original_utc_time
```

it is adding/subtracting '700'/'800' hours instead of 7/8 hrs to the original timestamp because the offset is a VARCHAR and the values are like: `-0700` etc.

Did anyone see this issue before? Appreciate any help/inputs. Thanks.

Comment: is the offset column text?

Comment: Yes John. It is a text

Answer (score 1):

Just take the 'hours' part of the offset:

```
WITH t as (
SELECT  '2011-06-22 11:00:00.000000'::timestamp as original_timestamp, '-0700' as original_timezone_offset
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-11-29 17:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'-0800'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-12-02 22:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'+0900'
)
SELECT
  original_timestamp,
  original_timezone_offset,
  DATEADD(hour, SUBSTRING(original_timezone_offset, 1, 3)::INT, original_timestamp)
FROM t

2011-06-22 11:00:00 -0700   2011-06-22 04:00:00
2014-11-29 17:00:00 -0800   2014-11-29 09:00:00
2014-12-02 22:00:00 +0900   2014-12-03 07:00:00
```

You'll need some additional fancy code if you have non-full-hour offsets (eg +0730).

Answer (score 1):

First, recognize that if your timestamps are already in local time of the given offset, then you need to *subtract* that offset to convert back to UTC.  In that first example you gave, `2011-06-22 11:00:00 -0700` is equivalent to `2011-06-22 18:00:00 UTC`.

However, rather than try to add or subtract these values yourself, you should let the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_AT_TIME_ZONE.html) function do the work for you.  It will create a `timestamptz` that is in your supplied offset, then you can use it again to convert to UTC.

(Note that you could use the [`CONVERT_TIMEZONE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html) function instead, but that one is only understood by Redshift, where `AT TIME ZONE` works on regular PostgreSQL also.)

However, you have is that the time zone offsets you have aren't in a format understood by these functions.  See [time zone usage notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html#CONVERT_TIMEZONE-usage-notes).  So, before we try to convert, let's translate your offset strings to an understood format.

We will want `-0700` to become `+07:00`.  The colon is required, and the sign must be flipped because it will be interpreted with the POSIX-style time zone format.  In that format, positive values lie *west* of GMT instead of the usual conventions specified in ISO 8601.

```
concat(translate(substring(original_timezone_offset, 1, 3), '-+', '+-'),':',substring(original_timezone_offset, 4, 2))
```

Then we will use that with `AT TIME ZONE` to do the conversion:

```
(original_timezone AT TIME ZONE <the above mess>) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_timestamp
```

Putting it all together...

```
WITH t as (
SELECT  '2011-06-22 11:00:00.000000'::timestamp as original_timestamp, '-0700' as original_timezone_offset
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-11-29 17:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'-0800'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-12-02 22:00:00.000000'::timestamp,'+0900'
)
SELECT
  original_timestamp,
  original_timezone_offset,
  concat(translate(substring(original_timezone_offset, 1, 3), '-+', '+-'),':',substring(original_timezone_offset, 4, 2)) as modified_timezone_offset,
  (original_timestamp AT TIME ZONE concat(translate(substring(original_timezone_offset, 1, 3), '-+', '+-'),':',substring(original_timezone_offset, 4, 2))) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_timestamptz
FROM t
```

Output:

```
2011-06-22 11:00:00  -0700  +07:00  2011-06-22 18:00:00
2014-11-29 17:00:00  -0800  +08:00  2014-11-30 01:00:00
2014-12-02 22:00:00  +0900  -09:00  2014-12-02 13:00:00
```

[SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/27170)